# Writing to OutputStream in JavaFX setOnAction() method

Tags: java, javafx

I am writing a JavaFX application (it is supposed to be a simple chat application). For now, I am trying to write on an `OutputStream` every time a button is pressed. The fact is that it is not working, it looks like the info is written but I cannot read it from the `InputStream`.

I have two classes: one of them is the interface (`extends Application`). It has a `TextField` and a "Send" button. When I write something in the text field and press this button, the text from the `TextField` is written to the `OutputStream`. On the other hand, another class, which is a `Thread`, is reading from the `InputStream`. Even though the information is written to the stream, the `readLine()` method is not working, it keeps waiting for data to be received.

Is there something I'm missing? Thanks in advance.

**JavaFX Application**

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.Socket;
import javafx.application.Application;
import static javafx.application.Application.launch;
import javafx.geometry.*;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.*;
import javafx.scene.layout.*;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class ChatApp extends Application {

    int indexMsg = 0;

    Socket socket;
    BufferedReader br;
    PrintWriter pw;

    public ChatApp() throws IOException {

        this.socket = new Socket("localhost", 56700);
        this.pw = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream());
        this.br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));

    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws IOException {

        GridPane root = new GridPane();
        root.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        root.setVgap(10);
        root.setPadding(new Insets(10,10,10,10));

        ScrollPane msgPane = new ScrollPane();
        msgPane.setPrefSize(280, 280);
        msgPane.setHbarPolicy(ScrollPane.ScrollBarPolicy.NEVER);

        GridPane msgPaneContent = new GridPane();
        msgPaneContent.setPrefWidth(270);
        msgPaneContent.setVgap(10);

        FlowPane writePane = new FlowPane(10,10);
        writePane.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        writePane.setPrefWidth(280);

        TextField writeMsg = new TextField();
        writeMsg.setPrefWidth(200);
        writeMsg.setPromptText("Write your message");

        Button send = new Button("Send");


        send.setOnAction((ev) -> {
            TextArea msg = new TextArea(writeMsg.getText());
            msg.setMaxWidth(135);
            msg.setPrefRowCount(msg.getLength()/21 + 1);
            msg.setWrapText(true);

            GridPane.setConstraints(msg, 0, indexMsg++); 

            writeMsg.deleteText(0, writeMsg.getText().length());
            msgPaneContent.getChildren().add(msg);

            String message = msg.getText();

            pw.write(message);
            System.out.println("Sent " + msg.getText());

        });

        writePane.getChildren().addAll(writeMsg, send);

        GridPane.setConstraints(msgPane, 0, 0);
        GridPane.setConstraints(writePane, 0, 1);

        msgPane.setContent(msgPaneContent);
        root.getChildren().addAll(msgPane, writePane);

        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 300);

        primaryStage.setTitle("Chat App");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        launch(args);

    }

}
```

**Receiver Thread**

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;

public class ChatServer extends Thread {

    ServerSocket server;
    Socket socket;
    BufferedReader br;
    PrintWriter pw;

    public ChatServer() throws IOException {
        server = new ServerSocket(56700);
        socket = server.accept();
        br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
        pw = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream());

    }

    public void run() {
        String msg = null;

        while (true) {

            try {
                msg = br.readLine();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                System.out.println("Error");
            }

            System.out.println(msg);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException {

        (new ChatServer()).start();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your message does not contain an end-of-line character. The `readLine()` method in the server reads everything in the stream, looking for an end of line marker and then concatenates all the characters to form the line of text. So you need to send an end-of-line character from the client.

You should also flush the print writer after sending the message - otherwise the print write may buffer many messages before actually sending them:

```
send.setOnAction((ev) -> {
    TextArea msg = new TextArea(writeMsg.getText());
    msg.setMaxWidth(135);
    msg.setPrefRowCount(msg.getLength()/21 + 1);
    msg.setWrapText(true);

    GridPane.setConstraints(msg, 0, indexMsg++); 

    writeMsg.deleteText(0, writeMsg.getText().length());
    msgPaneContent.getChildren().add(msg);

    String message = msg.getText();

    pw.write(message + "\n");
    pw.flush();

    System.out.println("Sent " + msg.getText());

});
```

Comment: Exactly, both corrections were necessary! Thank you so much.

Comment: As an aside: sending network I/O on the user interface thread may cause the application to become non-responsive.